# GNOME Shell extension for different applications in Dash by workspace?

Tags: software-recommendation, workspaces, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I'm looking for a GNOME Shell extension that will make it so that there are different applications showing up in the Dash depending on which workspace I'm on. Essentially, I want favorites segmented by workspace.

For example:

- Workspace 1 Dash (Personal): Thunderbird, Firefox, accounting app
- Workspace 2 Dash (Work): Gmail, Slack, Citrix

There is a "[Workspace Isolated Dash](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash/)" extension, which gets part way there by only showing favorites + applications with open windows on that workspace in Dash. But this doesn't segment favorites by workspace.

Any extensions that could do this? Or other ways to customize the GNOME Shell in this way?

Comment: Probably none exists yet. But you should try the [Auto Move Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/) extension if you're not using it yet. It launches specific applications in specific workspaces.